# MethodBeforeAdvice before method is not called

Tags: spring

Hi i think i found a bug in Spring .I was trying to use a simple MethodBeforeAdvice to check my login data before running some method here is the snapshot of the code.

public class Main {

```
public static void main(String []args){
    ProxyFactory pf = new ProxyFactory();
    SecureMessage sm = new SecureMessage();
    pf.setTarget(sm);
    pf.addAdvice(new SecurityAdvice());
    SecureMessage sm1 = (SecureMessage) pf.getProxy();
    sm1.showMessage();
}
```

Nothing special as you can see .When invoking showMessage() method i was expecting SecurityAdvice before method to be invoked first well it did not .But here is the super strange thing when i was in debug window and came to the last line.

```
sm1.showMessage();
```

i wanted to see if sm1 is a proxy so i clicked on it in Variables window and what do you know the before method got invoked .Even stranger i can click on it as many times i like and the method will be invoked.
Dose any body have an idea what is happening hear ?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer the reason it did not work is because showMessage() was a static method.It seems MethodBeforeAdvice  before method doesn't work for static methods .As for the debuging issue i have no clue.